# Different results in linux OS than my Windows OS

Tags: c, linux, windows

```
void destroi_playlist_na_jukebox(jukebox j,char* resto)
{
    int i,k=1,musicas_numero;
    char nome_playlist[MAX_LINHA];
    playlist remove_playlist;

    i= sscanf(resto,"%[^\n^\r]",nome_playlist);


    if( (i==1) && (verifica_existe_playlist(j,nome_playlist) == 1) )
    {
        remove_playlist = (playlist)tira_playlist_jukebox(j,nome_playlist);
        musicas_numero = numero_musicas(remove_playlist);

        if( musicas_numero > 0 )
        {
            while( k <= musicas_numero )
            {
               remove_musica(remove_playlist,1);
               k++;
             }

        }
        destroiGenPlaylist( (void *) remove_playlist);
        printf("Playlist eliminada.\n");
    }
    else
       if( (verifica_existe_playlist(j,nome_playlist) !=1) && (i==1) ) // Problem is here
       {
           printf("Playlist inexistente.\n");
       }
           else printf("Dados invalidos.\n");
 }
```

The problem is in the last if statement. I get resto which doesnt obey the first if statement and goes to the second one, everything good there but the problem is that on my computer (it has a windows os) it prints "Dados invalidos" for some reason and on my college compiler (based on a linux os) it prints "Playlist inexistente". What's happening and how can i solve it? The right answer is what prints on my computer.

Comment: Can you post **minimal**, **complete**, and **compilable** **reproducable** code ?

Comment: Giving a quick look, your issue might not be in the function you posted. Can you confirm if the `verifica_existe_playlist` returns the same value on both machines or not?
If `verifica_existe_playlist` returns different values, then it's the problem.

Comment: Already solved this problem, so this post can be ignored. But thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n^\r]", ...` you don't want to consider newlines, carriage returns, and carets for your variable? That's unexpected :)

Answer (score 2):

You are checking on `\r\n`, which is Windows line ending. Linux/UNIX line ending is simply `\n`. So you might first check which system you're working on and see how to proceed, or you might search for a function which checks this automatically.